# How to get Grails to ignore .DS_Store

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 2.3.3 on OS X 10.9 (Maverick). I'm finding that if I use Finder to browse the directory structure it will create a .DS_Store file in each directory (as per usual). This is causing grails to spit out numerous errors, so I'm wondering if I can just tell grails to ignore all .DS_Store files.

Details as follows.

So after browsing with Finder, if I go to 'grails test-app' I receive an abundance of error messages and stack traces. Example (stack trace goes on for many many more lines - so just a sample):

```
| Error Unable to obtain resource from /Users/Stevenson/grails/testApp/grails-app/.DS_Store: 
| Error java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
| Error     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
| Error     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
| Error     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
| Error     at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153)
| Error     at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:117)
| Error     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1006)
| Error     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResource(AntClassLoader.java:887)
```

This only occurs when it needs to recompile one/any of my unit tests - as in, I've made a change. And, no errors are reported when I 'grails run-app'.

The only slight assistance I found was this link (which kinda says too bad):
https://github.com/beckje01/grails-code-coverage/issues/14

However, not sure if that's only related to the Code Coverage plugin, or Grails in general.

Currently, the only solution I have is:

- Don't browse the directory structure with Finder; and
- If I do then run the below find command to tidy up.

Find tidy up command:

```
find . -name '.DS_Store' -exec rm {} +
```

But surely you can just ignore a specified file.... surely... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is fixed for Grails 2.3.4, [as mentioned here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10594). The workaround for 2.3.3 is:

> Also getting this same issue. For me, I simply had to remove a
>   .DS_Store from the root of the project, and the grails-app folder -
>   and at that point all errors went away.